# How to measure amount of data sent and received by a specific app?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10

I would like to get a total amount of bytes that is sent and received by a specific program.

I know I get totals for the entire machine by selecting Status off the Network Card's context menu, but not per app.

Is this possible?

Comment: I like this software for that...http://seriousbit.com/netbalancer/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this *Mark Russinovich* Microsoft tool

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

You can create a filter for your process Name or PID in **Filter** menu.
Then go to **Tools** menu and **Network Summary**.

Or with

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview

**If you have powershell notion and you want to write your own tool:**

French:

```
get-counter "\Processus(firefox*)\Nombre d’octets lus/s" -Continuous | foreach {
    [math]::round((($_.countersamples.cookedvalue | measure -sum).sum / 1KB), 2)
}
```

English

```
get-counter "\Process(firefox*)\IO Read Bytes/sec" -Continuous | foreach {
    [math]::round((($_.countersamples.cookedvalue | measure -sum).sum / 1KB), 2)
}
```

Work with this code and this loop .Create a total variable and assign calculated sum in each iteration. Adjust KB, can be MB, GB ...

Save this script into a file .ps1 ,open **command prompt** and execute this script, (CTRL+C for stop)

```
$process="firefox"
$totalKB = 0
while($true){    
    get-counter "\Process($process*)\IO Read Bytes/sec" | foreach {
        $totalKB += [math]::round((($_.countersamples.cookedvalue | measure -sum).sum / 1KB), 2)
    }
    Write-Host -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow ("`r"+$process.ToUpper()+": "+([string]$totalKB)+" KB    ")
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
}
write-host
```

RESULT (LIVE same as Linux Watch for example)

> FIREFOX: 3256 KB

**Ref:**

> https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/01/31/use-powershell-to-simplify-collecting-performance-information/

Comment: using wireshark is a bad idea, since an app can have more than one data flow

Comment: This is true, i have edited my answer.